# Allow only positive number with text input mask

Tags: .net-3.5, input, maskedtextbox, negative-number

I true to set a text input mask which only allow numbers from 0-999, or even better 1-999.

So I tried the mask "##0", but unfortunately this also allows negative numbers. Is there a way to allow only positive numbers?

Best regards,
Enyra

Answer (score 1):

990 should work just fine as far as I understand your question. This will make space an allowed character for the two first digits, and the last one is always required to be a number.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it out, but I just found out, that the text edit control from DevExpress does not support all masks :(